# How to listen to drags with DragListener, but pass clicks through to Views below?

Tags: android, android-touch-event

How can the code below be changed so that when there's a click style touch event (not a drag) the click is passed down to the Views below (at the same position) to be handled? I expected either performClick() or returning false to have that effect, but apparently not.

```
private inner class DragListener : OnTouchListener {

    private var isDrag = false

    override fun onTouch(v: View, event: MotionEvent): Boolean {
        when (event.action) {

            MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {
                isDrag = false
                startAngle = getAngle(event.x.toDouble(), event.y.toDouble())
            }

            MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE -> {
                val currentAngle = getAngle(event.x.toDouble(), event.y.toDouble())
                doDragStuff()
                isDrag = false
            }

            MotionEvent.ACTION_UP -> {
                if (!isDrag) {
                    // HOW TO PASS CLICK DOWN HERE?
                    v.performClick()
                    return false
                }
            }
        }
        return true
    }
```

Comment: try return false from action down too

Comment: That didn't make any difference unfortunately.